# MVC - Strongly typed view not returning primary key but form collection does it

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel, formcollection

I have a view and model. Inside the solution, I have used Code first design pattern to create Model classes with [KEY] attributes to mark a primary.

By default I used MVC dialog box to create CURD views, the problem is I can get the primary key value from model but when I post the information from Edit view all I see is zero in primary key field instead of 1.

I knew I'm doing something wrong but couldn't find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: View with model : http://i.stack.imgur.com/lzqAH.png
Code first Model : http://i.stack.imgur.com/hjZ9h.png
Action with Model :http://i.stack.imgur.com/m7LGu.png
Action with Form collection : http://i.stack.imgur.com/IeAkC.png
BY this way I can see primary key is posted to action but any how the model is not getting it

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my model Primary Key from CustomerId to Id. Now the model is receiving the Primary key or I should use custom ModelBinder class.